# Finding the ratio

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working with mobile screen resolutions (dpi).

at 320dpi = 640 pixels

at 250dpi = 500 pixels

If I wanted to use the above pattern, how would I calculate to change the dpi value to make it 
x dpi = 480 pixel ?

Please ask if I am being vague and I will try and explain it further.

I am looking for a formula that finds the difference of how much to divide on each side I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac{x}{480}=\frac{320}{640}=\frac{250}{500}$, so $x=240$.